# How to use JUnit suite to intercept tests with @before

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit4

I want to run my existing tests two times, one time with Log level set to TRACE and one time with Log level set to ERROR. To achieve this I tried to use a test suite and added a method which I annotated with `@Before`.

The code base itself is written with Spring Boot and the default logger is configured to Log level TRACE, so the normal test execution is using Log level TRACE, which is good for the first run.

For the run with the suite, where all tests are configured a second time, I expected that the `@Before` annotated method would be called before every test that is executed, but it is not.

The only effect I could see is when I call `@BeforeClass`, then it is called one time. Since every test will start up the spring context from scratch, my overridden Log level is only used at the first test that is executed.

Here's my test suite, any idea to achieve this?

```
@RunWith(ParallelSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses("**/*Test.class")
@Log4j2
public class TestSuiteWithErrorLogger {

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    Logger controller = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("komposit.guidewire.controller");
    root.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    controller.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    log.error("set logging to warn so that all tests will be called without log statements");
}

@Before
public void before() {
    Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    Logger controller = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("komposit.guidewire.controller");
    root.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    controller.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    log.error("set logging to warn before every test in this suite");
}

@ClassRule
public static ExternalResource testRule = new ExternalResource() {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        Logger controller = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("komposit.guidewire.controller");
        root.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        controller.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        log.error("set logging to error with a custom rule");
    };

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        log.error("after finishing a test logging is still on error");
    };
};
}
```

Comment: One approach you can try is to configure the application-test.properties using the profile 'test' you can configure two log files one with the TRACE level the other with the ERROR level, this way you don't need to run twice.

Comment: Thanks vladwoguer, that sounds like a promising solution, will try it.